# Removing overlapping polygons common to multiple layers in QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, overlapping-features

I have 2 different layers of tax parcels, but there is an overlapping parcel common to both which I would like to eliminate. See the screenshot below of this overlapping parcel:

[image]

This is a simple example in which the common parcel can obviously be eliminated manually. But I may be working with several layers where the overlap may be 40 or 50 common / overlapping tax parcels.

Is there an automated or process-based way of eliminating any overlapping polygons *from multiple layers*? Or at least a way of selecting overlapping polygons from multiple layers to then delete? Most of the solutions I found involve removing overlapping polygons within the *same* layer.

Comment: Does their geometry match completely?

Comment: Yes, it's a total and complete overlap. No "sliver" polygons here, as both layers come from the same data source.

Comment: Check this out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314267/35561

Comment: Also `Overlap analysis` might help you: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgiscalculatevectoroverlaps

Comment: Semi-manual way: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/172915/35561

Comment: I don't have much experience running Python code within QGIS, so I'll have to do some trial-and-error. Thanks for the links!

Comment: Depending on what you need, if they are all from the same source you could: 1. run Difference overlays to in effect erase overlaps, or 2. make sure each layer has its name or unique code in its attributes and merge them, then run the delete duplicate geometries tool, or run the SAGA polygon self intersection tool which will tell you the ids of overlapping polygons which you can deal with in many ways.  Then split vector layer tool to get your separate layers back.